# Handling Jquery-ui Autocomplete's label value pairs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using [Jquery-ui Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) extension. Here's how i use it:

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
  <input id="auto" name="label" type="text" />
  <input id="coauto" name="value" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>

<script>
    $('#auto').autocomplete({
         source: [{label: 'milan', value: 1}, {label: 'inter', value: 2}, {label: 'juventus', value: 3}]
    })
</script>
```

When i click 'm', `milan` shows up. I have no problem with that. However i want value of milan (which is 1) as `#coauto's` value.So i can send them to `example.php`. How can i do that? I dont see anything about `value` while `label` working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callback functions like focus or select.
For rendering you can use

> .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

Here is a sample code just to give you an idea.

```
$('#auto').autocomplete({
         source: [{label: 'milan', value: 1}, {label: 'inter', value: 2}, {label: 'juventus', value: 3}]
         ,

            focus : function(event, ui) {

                $("#coauto").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },

            select : function(event, ui) {
                $("#coautoFormField").val(ui.item.value);

                $("#hautoDetailsForm").submit();
                return false;
            }

    })
```

Comment: why we say `return false;` at the end?

Comment: focus(event, ui) 
This event is triggered whenever one of the menu choices receives focus. Unless canceled (for example, by returning false), the focused value is set into the <input> element. Ref : [link] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm)

Comment: In short, generally when you return false, it means you have handled that event.

Comment: thanks for helping me. Its working but `#auto` does not change  as i focus on items. Can you suggest any solution??? I used `focus: function(event ,ui){}`